# output a PHP variable containg html structure as is without being interpreted by browser

Tags: php, html

```
$html = '<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>';
print_r($html);
```

The above code will only display "foo" in browser with a link attached to it.
How do I output the actual value of $html as is(I want the browser to display `<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>`) ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://docs.php.net//manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$html = '<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>';
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

That will encode any characters that have special meaning in html and can potentially break your html.

Comment: Thank you! I spent a lot of time googling but could never get to this function.. hmmm.. just don't know how to choose the key words right..

Answer (score 2):

You might also know about the function [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). It can be used to convert all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents into these entities. This is escpecially interesting if your HTML document encoding is not utf-8.

Please see the discussion below.

Comment: Would use `htmlentities`? Seems to be it only makes the response larger without any gain for OP.

Comment: As you mentioned `htmlentities` converts ALL characters (for which there is an entity) when this really isn't needed. So basically you are potentially giving the client back a larger string / response than is necessary.

Comment: The documentation doesn't tell much about the `all`. If I got you correctly, this would lead to `&uuml;` for German `ü` in the output. Yes? But what is wrong with that?

Comment: Isn't `htmlentities()` a bit a thing of the past, when most html documents used latin / iso encodings?

Comment: Correct @hek2mgl. Why would you make a document more heavy for no good reason?

Comment: @PeeHaa Maybe I should rethink this? My usage of this function started in times when `utf-8` was not the de-facto standard for HTML sites. I'll reword this answer and think about it. thx for the hint!

Comment: @jeroen Thanks too. Yes, it looks like you both are right. I'll keep the answer, maybe it helps somebody other to see the difference.